# change encoding,rails and mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding

I did not mention encoding in my database.yml file.And now after parsing a site,a lot of data is saved with special characters.

Is there a way to change or set the encoding to utf-8 now?And what is the best way to do it,would really appreciate if you can explain it with little snippets of code.

Or do I need to do the parsing again.

Comment: Doing the  parsing again with the correct encoding specified would probably be the easiest way.

Comment: ya but it would take hours again,so if there is another way i would really prefer that

Comment: You'll need to show *how* your characters are broken exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do it without reconfiguring configurations and fixing existing data. Else, you will end up corrupting your db (some data in one encoding and some in another)

This should help:

1. [converting-your-rails-app-to-utf8](http://tumblelog.jauderho.com/post/27806549/converting-your-rails-app-to-utf8)
2. [configure-rails-and-mysql-to-support-utf-8](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/09/14/configure-rails-and-mysql-to-support-utf-8/)